# Highchart export not applying style(font size) on series data labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a column chart using High Charts -- I want to **export** the well formed chart to **PNG** image, I am able to apply all the necessary style for exporting but **I am not able to apply style on series data labels while exporting**-- **I want them to be of reduced font size in exported image**.

I am inserting code here but somehow the export link/button is not appearing in the chart below

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bhupendrasinghnegi/s0uj4Lkk/)

**[image: Refer the [Fiddle Sample][1] to have hands on, and **attached** required output image]**

Prompt help will highly be appreciated.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  navigation: {
    menuStyle: {
      background: '#E0E0E0'
    },
    buttonOptions: {
      theme: {
        style: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
          color: '#039',
          textDecoration: 'underline'
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            fill: 'white' //'#a4edba'
          },
          select: {
            stroke: '#039',
            fill: 'white'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        enabled: false

      },
      exportButton: {
        text: 'Download', //'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>',
        menuItems: [{
          textKey: 'downloadPNG',
          onclick: function() {
            this.exportChart();
          }
        }, {
          textKey: 'downloadJPEG',
          onclick: function() {
            this.exportChart({
              type: 'image/jpeg'
            });
          }
        }]
      },
    },
    enabled: true,
    filename: 'Industry Data Set',
    sourceWidth: 380,
    sourceHeight: 300,
    chartOptions: { // specific options for the exported image
      legend: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          pointWidth: 10,
          groupPadding: 0,
          dataLabels: {
            enable: true,
            style: {
              fontSize: "10px",
              fontWeight: "normal"
            }
          }

        },

      },
      xAxis: {
        //lineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
          rotate: -45,
          enabled: true,
          //format: "{value:.0f}",
          style: {
            fontSize: "6px",
            fontFamily: "Arial"
          }
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
          text: "Count",
          style: {
            fontFamily: "Arial",
            fontSize: "8px",
          }
        },
        labels: {
          //rotate: -45,
          enabled: true,
          format: "{value:.0f}",
          style: {
            fontSize: "6px",
            fontFamily: "Arial"
          }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0
      },
    },
    //scale: 2,
    fallbackToExportServer: false
  }, // Exporting End

  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['#00Aeef', '#f4b213', '#9cc84b', '#2bc4b6', '#8d64aa', '#0a3f6b', '#aa5019'],
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Industries'
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',

    lineWidth: 1,
    tickWidth: 0,
    title: {
      text: "",
      style: {
        fontFamily: "Arial"
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 1,
    title: {
      text: "Count",
      style: {
        fontFamily: "Arial"
      }
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: "{value:.0f}",
      style: {
        fontSize: "8px",
        fontFamily: "Arial"
      }
    },
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: 'Count <b>{point.y}</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointWidth: 20,
      groupPadding: 0,
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Population',
    data: [
      ['Shanghai', 23.7],
      ['Lagos', 16.1],
      ['Istanbul', 14.2],
      ['Karachi', 14.0],
      ['Mumbai', 12.5],
      ['Moscow', 12.1],
      ['São Paulo', 11.8],
      ['Beijing', 11.7],
      ['Guangzhou', 11.1],
      ['Delhi', 11.1],
      ['Shenzhen', 10.5],
      ['Seoul', 10.4],
      ['Jakarta', 10.0],
      ['Kinshasa', 9.3],
      ['Tianjin', 9.3],
      ['Tokyo', 9.0],
      ['Cairo', 8.9],
      ['Dhaka', 8.9],
      ['Mexico City', 8.9],
      ['Lima', 8.9]
    ],
    dataLabels: {
      rotation: -90,
      y: -17,
      align: "center",
      enabled: true,
      borderColor: "",
      style: {
        fontSize: "10px",
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontFamily: "Arial",
        textShadow: false
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; height: 470px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to overwrite `series` options in the exporting property. `plotOptions.series` will not affect the series because options for a specific series have  higher priority.

```
exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
       series: [{
         dataLabels: {
           style: {
             fontSize: "6px",
             fontWeight: "normal"
           }
         }
       }],
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/s0uj4Lkk/2/

Comment: morangree: Thanks for the support. While your fix works well on JSFiddle but not on actual .js file in my project

Please find the sample gif image here [link] (https://mxhqkq-dm2306.files.1drv.com/y3p7BPUodSbkFc48Lga7YFChKPvVj6h6RRn61k7dj9YzbG-EK8DdEanEJUpiuiaVEn5_-yO19ifNa8DtbJydizPrEBarEHbqoanOOjc_Ls58sSL2wzmOiB7N46FfyQcmAQymVHw9Yf_K47r3Gik-ud0qg/Not%20Working%20Sample.gif?psid=1)

Comment: What version of Highcharts do you use?

Comment: I am using  Highcharts JS v4.2.5 (2016-05-06)

Comment: It seems that in the older version, matching series does not work in the way that in the newer. You can update the series on load callback - the callback can be set in the exporting options. http://jsfiddle.net/s0uj4Lkk/3/

Comment: I am using js ver 5 and 'update the series on load callback' as the only thing that helped me. thx very much @morganfree